# How to assign a variable to a control's content

Tags: c, winapi, variables, controls

```
HWND hStatic = CreateWindowEx( 0, "STATIC", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE |
SS_LEFT, 40, 30, 150, 20, hwnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL );
SetWindowText( hStatic, "the variable"  );
```

I am trying to learn the Windows API and am using a tutorial in my language, but it seems it does not have an answer to my question.
I would like to make a small textbox (made it this far) and make it so that I'll assign a variable to it, so that when the textbox contents change the variable is updated to hold the number entered. But I don't know how to actually connect those 2 entities.
In a console application I can use `cin >>`, but if I use it here it will show me the cmd instead of the window.
I didn't see anyone asking for something similar and I can't find the answer in my tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Windows API, you cannot assign a variable to a control, so that it will automatically update. You will have to do this manually. The moral equivalents of `cin` and `cout` are [`GetWindowText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520.aspx) and [`SetWindowText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633546.aspx). Both API calls deal with character strings only. If you need the control's content as a number you have to convert it, using [`atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) and friends.

To be informed whenever the text in an edit control changes, the edit control's parent window's window procedure should handle the [`EN_CHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761676.aspx) notification.